# Finding/replacing/dropping a string which is partially duplicated

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I have a pandas dataframe which contains company names.
Sometimes it also includes the location or a subdivision in the name (e.g. McDonalds Boston, McDonalds Washington. PwC accounting, PwC advisory).
I am only interested in getting the company name (i.e. McDonalds), not the locality.

To make this more complicated, some words will show up in multiple company names, but should remain there. (e.g. airlines). Now, I can create a list with these exceptions. I just don't know how to implement a search for partial matches, or how to use an exclusion list to make sure we don't capture these cases.

So, I currently have:

```
 PwC advisory
 PwC accounting
 American airlines
 McDonalds Boston
 McDonalds Washington
 Spirit airlines
```

What I need is:

```
 PwC
 American airlines
 McDonalds 
 Spirit airlines
```

I was thinking that I might have to resort to splitting each string into its words, excluding the words from my exclusion list (like airlines) and then checking if any of the parts of 1 string are in any of the parts of any of the other strings. This seems like a very roundabout way of doing it, and I wouldn't know how to do it.

Comment: So you haven't actually tried to write anything to solve this problem, correct?

Comment: I was trying to come up with something, but the only solution I could conceive of was going to include a loop in which I create separate lists of words for each name and check one by one if the words in 1 list are in any of the others. That did not seem like an efficient solution, nor was I sure how to program it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a regex here and [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
import re

exceptions = ['airlines']
pattern = fr'(\S+(?: (?:{"|".join(map(re.escape, exceptions))}))?)'
# '(\\S+(?: (?:airlines))?)'

df['name'] = df['col'].str.extract(pattern, expand=False)
```

Output:

```
                    col               name
0          PwC advisory                PwC
1        PwC accounting                PwC
2     American airlines  American airlines
3      McDonalds Boston          McDonalds
4  McDonalds Washington          McDonalds
5       Spirit airlines    Spirit airlines
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is like to find the longest common prefix. So, the idea is to explode company names into single words (tokenize) then compare the current row to the previous one and keep only common words:

```
names = df['Company'].sort_values().str.split(expand=True)
m1 = names == names.shift()
m2 = m1.shift(-1, fill_value=False)

df['Name'] = (names.mul(m1 | m2).replace('', np.nan)
                   .mask(lambda x: x.isna().all(axis=1), other=names)
                   .stack().groupby(level=0).agg(' '.join))
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                Company               Name
0          PwC advisory                PwC
1  McDonalds Washington          McDonalds
2     American airlines  American airlines
3      McDonalds Boston          McDonalds
4       Spirit airlines    Spirit airlines
5        PwC accounting                PwC
```

Details:

```
>>> pd.concat([names, m2|m1, m1, m2], keys=['names', 'm1|m2', 'm1', 'm2'], axis=1)

       names              m1|m2            m1            m2       
           0           1      0      1      0      1      0      1
2   American    airlines  False  False  False  False  False  False
3  McDonalds      Boston   True  False  False  False   True  False
1  McDonalds  Washington   True  False   True  False  False  False
5        PwC  accounting   True  False  False  False   True  False
0        PwC    advisory   True  False   True  False  False  False
4     Spirit    airlines  False  False  False  False  False  False
```